# Approval Process after submitted

Tags: approval-process

I have a custom object record is sent for approval process in submitted stage. Now the related list of the record also should be locked i.e. it should not be changed by certain users. Is there any possibility for it thanks.

Comment: In the related list we have a custom object called Opportunity line item . We need to lock the records of opportunity line item .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validation rule to do this.
Create the following validation rule example on "opportunity products" object whenever its related opportunity stage = 'Submitted'.
Formula will be something like below.

(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, "Submitted")

Hope this resolves your issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it helped me . AND(

ISPICKVAL(Implementation__r.Status__c,"Submitted"),

($User.Alias = "cfran")||($User.Alias="breut")

)